# Buffer Overflow Probem

Tags: overflow

I'm trying to do a class exercise, but I have a problem.

When I put "A" in the scanf, I can produce a buffer overflow (segmentation fault), but when I put a Shellcode and more conten Ex. shellcode + A*40 the code exited normally.

I feel the problem is that shellcodes has x0b and the line cant continue.

Could you help me?

Comment: You should provide some code and tell us your programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should not be what is inside the shellcode as it is just bytes that are stored on the stack.

I suggest this reading : https://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html
It explains how to perform buffer overflows in multiple situations (which might look like your class exercise).